# Register with meteor using express

Tags: node.js, express, meteor

I want to call Accounts.createUser on my register routing, i pretty sure i'm doing something wrong.

```
app.post('/register', (req, res, next) => {
Accounts.createUser(email,password,username)
}
```

Is there a way to call a meteor method on express ??

Comment: Does this code give you an error? If so can you edit your question to include it?

Answer (score 2):

If you are needing integrate your Express backend with your Meteor accounts, I would recommend you look account-js (as a decoupled way of manage accounts like Meteor accounts). It is possible integrate your user accounts between Meteor and Express, as an interesting use case.

Take a look at it: https://accounts-js.netlify.com

Github project: https://github.com/accounts-js/accounts

Meteor integration: http://accounts-js.netlify.com/docs/cookbook/meteor

Enjoy!